# Binding properties to CustomDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, celltemplate

I have a list of items

```
public List<Item> MyItems { get; set; }
```

displayed on the DataGrid. One column shows status "icon" which is defined by template.
Code looks something like that:

Column template [...]

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Height="18" Width="35">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Status.Background}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status.Text}" />
      </Grid>   
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>    
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Data model [...]

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; } 
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
public class Status
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public int Text { get; set; }

    public Brush Background
    {
      get
      {
         //Colour logic goes here
      }
    }
}
```

I'd like to remove colour logic from the data model and put it to the resource file instead.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyCustomTemplate}" </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I hope so far I am going to right direction but at this point I am lost as I don't know how to bind Status property (or StatusId) to MyCustomTemplate.

If anyone could help my with this it would be great.

**EDIT**

This works fine.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="V" Width="25" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ic:CloseIcon  Visibility="{Binding DockStatus, Converter={StaticResource CloseIconDisplayVisibilityConverter}}" />
                <ic:DockIcon Visibility="{Binding DockStatus, Converter={StaticResource DockIconDisplayVisibilityConverter}}" />
                <ic:UndockIcon Visibility="{Binding DockStatus, Converter={StaticResource UndockIconDisplayVisibilityConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This doesn't refresh UI when model changes (DockStatus changes)

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="V" Width="25" IsReadOnly="True" CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DockIconCellTemplateSelector}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's only about selecting the proper background colour for a specific item, or items with a specific `StatusId`,  you could write a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter). The converter would simply convert an `int` to a `Brush`:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Brush))]
public class StatusColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            int statusId = (int)value;
            // create Brush from id here and return it
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You would modify your Binding like this:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Status.StatusId, Converter={StaticResource StatusColorConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. My problem is more complex and this was just an example. What I am really trying to do is to use a different template depends on model data bind to my column. Instead of CellTemplate I tried to use CellTemplateSelector (See the edit part) and but it doesn't refresh UI as it doesn't support INotifyPropertyChanged.